# how to know which tomcat is running in server

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I have two tomcat installed in Ec2 single Linux server.
tomcat1 path : /etc/tomcat/
tomcat2 path : /var/lib/tomcat/

server.xml file are all of the same in tomcat1 and tomcat2(connector port,redirectPort,protocol,...)
eg.
tomcat1 server.xml file

tomcat2 server.xml file

So, I think this server is running in single tomcat.How to know which tomcat is running in this server.tomcat1 ?tomcat2?Please Help Me.thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Looking up for `catalina.base` on the list of running processes might get the info

```
ps aux | sed -e '/catalina/ s/ [-]D/\n/g' | grep '^catalina\.base'
```

Result

```
catalina.base=/home/lmc/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1
catalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat
```